# Basic array with switch statements

Tags: java, arrays, loops, switch-statement

I have here my code here where I am doing some simple Array stuff. Originally this is the output of my work:

> - **Output:**
> - **Enter an item:** *_* // I don't know why I should have this.
> - **Main Menu**
>
>   1. Add Item //Display List
>   2. Remove Item //Display List; And searching for that particular item to be removed.
>   3. Sort Item //Listed
>
>      - Ascending Order
>      - Descending Order
>   4. Delete List //Should return to option 1 which is Add item
>   5. Exit

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;

public class MainArray{

    public static void main(String[] args){            
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;
        int array[] = new int[10]; //Default Size.

        choice = menu(user_input);            
        while(choice != 4){                
            switch (choice){                    
                case 1:  array = addItems(array, user_input);       break;
                case 2:  array = removeItems(array, user_input);    break;
                case 3:  array = sort(array);                       break;                    
                default:   break;
            }

            choice = menu(user_input);
        }            
        System.out.println("The End");            
    }

    public static int menu(Scanner user_input) {            
        System.out.println("\n-------");
        System.out.println("Here are your choices: \n" + "1: Add Items " + "2: Remove Items " + "3: Sort Items " + "4: End");
        System.out.println("-------");
        int choice = user_input.nextInt();
        return choice;
    }

    public static int[] addItems(int array[], Scanner user_input){       
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i ++){                
            System.out.print("Value #" + (i + 1) + ": ");                
            array[i] = user_input.nextInt();
        }            
        return array;
    }

    public static int[] removeItems(int array[], Scanner user_input){            
        System.out.println("Number to be removed: ");            
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i ++){
            System.out.println("Item removed: " + array[i]);                
            try {                    
                array[i] = user_input.nextInt();
            }               
            catch(Exception e){                    
                array[array.length - 1] = 0;
            }
        }            
        return array;
    }

    public static int[] sort(int array[]){
        System.out.println("Numbers in Ascending Order:");            
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i ++){                
            Arrays.sort(array);
            System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
        }            
        System.out.println("\nNumbers in Descending Order:");            
        for(int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i --){    
            System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
        }            
        return array;
    }
}
```

So now what I need are some assistance on how properly I can remove and delete my items. I know very well that my codes are wrong and some are right and most are mixed up. Basically this:

1. How to remove certain item in my list (e.g Value#1: 50, Value#2: 90, ... , Value#10: 1) and I want to remove what ever that is in ex. Value# 7.
2. How to properly show the list current/ before and after things where in the list.
3. Delete my list and lets you go back to option 1, which is, "Add Items".

Comment: You could use an ArrayList instead. That has methods for adding and removing single elements at specific locations. Also why do you call Arrays.sort several times? You only need to call it once.

Comment: the convetion is that method names start with lower case only.

Comment: @Elazar, don't change their code other than innocuous whitespace changes.  Changing the case of their method names is likely to cause more confusion than it is worth.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to manipulate the collection of integers after its creation, you need to use another type of collection, like ArrayList. You can initialize this type of collection this way:

```
List<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Notice that the collection requires Integer objects, but in most cases autoboxing and auto-unboxing will help you in passing and retrieving items from the collection. You can add() the integer you read in from the user to aList, as before, and Java takes care of wrapping it as an Integer object for you.

Once you create this collection, you can easily add() and remove() things. The remove() method takes simply the Object you want to remove, so you don't even need to know the index of that Object in the collection. In fact, there is also a clear() method you can call on the ArrayList, which will accomplish what you mentioned in terms of "deleting" all of the items that had been added, and starting over.

Now, regarding your loops...it seems awkward for you to iterate the length of the list in removeItems() and ask for an item to remove each time. What if the user only wants to remove a single item? It would probably be best to take out that *for* loop altogether, and leave it to the user to decide how many items to remove, by selecting that option from your menu as much as needed.

Finally, if you switch to the ArrayList approach, in your sort() method you will need to use instead the Collections.sort() method on your ArrayList. Once again, no need to place the Collections.sort() call within a *for* loop. That's just an inefficient thing to do, since you only need to sort yours once.

Here is an example of the approach I'm talking about. You'll want to try to add some input validation and such, but it serves as an illustration of how to use the ArrayList for the things you are trying to do:

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){            
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;

        List<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<>();

        choice = menu(user_input);            
        while(choice != 4){                
            switch (choice){                    
                case 1:  aList = Test.addItems(aList, user_input);       break;
                case 2:  aList = Test.removeItems(aList, user_input);    break;
                case 3:  Test.sort(aList);                   break;                    
                default:   break;
            }

            choice = menu(user_input);
        }            
        System.out.println("The End");            
    }

    public static int menu(Scanner user_input) {            
        System.out.println("\n-------");
        System.out.println("Here are your choices: \n" + "1: Add Items " 
            + "2: Remove Items " + "3: Sort Items " + "4: End");
        System.out.println("-------");
        int choice = user_input.nextInt();
        return choice;
    }

    public static List<Integer> addItems(List<Integer> nums, Scanner user_input){       
        nums.clear();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){                
            System.out.print("Value #" + (i + 1) + ": ");
            nums.add(user_input.nextInt());
        }
        return nums;
    }

    public static List<Integer> removeItems(List<Integer> nums, Scanner user_input){            
        System.out.println("Number to be removed: ");

        Integer remove = user_input.nextInt();
        if (nums.contains(remove)) {
            nums.remove(remove);
            System.out.println("Item removed: " + remove);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Number not found.");
        }
        return nums;
    }

    public static void sort(List<Integer> nums){
        System.out.println("Numbers in Ascending Order:");            
        Collections.sort(nums);
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + nums.get(i));
        }

        System.out.println("\nNumbers in Descending Order:");            
        for(int j = nums.size() - 1; j >= 0; j --){    
            System.out.print(" " + nums.get(j));
        }            
    }
}
```

For some more information on the List interface itself:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html

Comment: Well I was very well aware that my case 2 was a problem, so right now I am trying to solve that problem with all the help I could get from the people who knows Java better than I. :D

Comment: This is so dumb of me. I just realized that I am using JCreator since its the only program at the moment that we are using at school. No wonder that some of the codes aren't working. They're for Eclipse. D: